# ui-router $stateProvider text parameter not displaying with ui-view, AngularJS 1.6.x

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Learning to use AngularJS (1.6.x) and ui-router and just trying to pass a simple text string (GOOD TEST) from a single $stateProvider.state parameter before I try more complicated things. Poured through other SO posts and AngularJS docs. My code has no syntax errors (komodo edit 11), and no angular reference or loading errors or any errors in console. Browser is chrome v66.0.x. The class/link to the state (US Calculator) and the URL are both executing just fine on the page. Just nothing happens when I click on the class to activate it. Guessing the .configs in the javascript are not set up properly. HTML and JS code follows:

```js
angular
    .module('myTestApp', ['ui-router'])

.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('usCalculator', {
            url: '/usCalculator',
            template: 'GOOD TEST'
        });
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myTestApp.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  
  <div class="container" ng-app="myTestApp">
      <a href="#/usCalculator">US Calculator</a>
      <div ui-view>
      </ui-view>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 `ng-app` in your `html` and you are inserting `"ui-router"` , it should be `"ui.router"`

[Check this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/c77xkP7R5X7w2QvU4pd9?p=preview)

```
angular.module('myTestApp', ["ui.router"])
```

Comment: Thank you @Shashank Vivek! When I toyed around with ui-sref before posting, it didn't work for me, but clearly bcz of the other problems.

Comment: @mljon . It happens ;) . If it helped, upvote this ans as well plz

Comment: I did up vote. But apparently I'm too new to SO that my vote "isn't visible" :(. Guess I have to accumulate more points. As soon as I do, will up vote it. Btw, what editor do you use? Wondering why my editor didn't catch the errors

Comment: tried. can't do that either. per the alert "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation points are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." it rips